# finding non-java files from a java class

Tags: java, classpath

I'm not working in any development environment like Eclipse or NetBeans. I work from the Windows Terminal. My root folder is Project, containing src, res, bin.

res contains -png files that i want to use in the java classes in the src folder. Now I'm confused because manually ordering the structure of the files and folders in my Project have no influence on how my code behaves. I still need to declare what package a class lies in in the code. I can't declare (in code) that Image1.png lies in the package res. How do my classes then find this image?

I have tried putting the image in the same package as the class that wants access and simply trying `getResource("Image1.png")` but no: NullPointerException.

Nobody seems to have this problem and I can't find answers anywhere.

the layout of my project:

```
Project
  bin
    samplecode
      SampleCodeClass1.class
      SampleCodeClass2.class
  res
    Image1.png
  src
    samplecode
      SampleCodeClass1.java
      SampleCodeClass2.java
```

now when I open a Terminal from the Project directory and enter:

`java -cp bin;res samplecode.SampleCodeClass1`

i get `at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)`

referring to this line in my code:

`ImageIcon ii =    new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("Image1.png"));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to understand that the classpath that matters is the one used at runtime. Not when compiling the Java source files. If the structure is

```
bin
    com
        foo
            MyClass.class
res
    com
        foo
            Image1.png
```

then you'll be able to use `MyClass.class.getResource("Image1.png")` or `AnyClassInAnyPackage.class.getResource("/com/foo/Image1.png")`, provided that the `res` folder is in the runtime classpath:

```
java -cp bin;res com.foo.MyClass
```

If the `res` folder is not in the classpath, then it can't be loaded by the ClassLoader.

EDIT:

The image is in the default package. The class is in the package samplecode. So they're not in the same package. So you can't use `this.getClass().getResource("Image1.png")`, which would look for the image in the same package as the class. Instead, you must use the full path of the image from the root of the classpath, starting with a `/`: `this.getClass().getResource("/Image1.png")`

Comment: You're talking quite over my head. How do I put the res folder in the classpath and.. what does it mean?

Comment: The only things in my bin folder (after compilation) are the classes in the src-folder. Because quite obviously i can't compile the res-folder

Comment: with the `-cp` (or `-classpath`, if you prefer typing more characters) option of java, which must contain a list of paths to directories or jar files. See my example: the classpath would contain the bin folder (to find the .class files) and the res folder (to find the images).

Comment: I can't make this work and it frustrates me beyond belief. I entered your code snippet and still get a NullPointerException. But I would imagine even though I tell the JVM to look for "Image1.png" in the res-folder it can't find it because I never actually created that folder! Only in windows, if you know what I mean?

Comment: Then edit your question, and tell us more about what you're actually doing. What's the layout of the project? What's the code causing the exception? What's the exception stack trace? Which command are you executing, and from which directory? And no, I don't understand what you mean with the res folder. How can you have a res folder without having created it?

Comment: if I put HelloWorld.java in a helloworld folder, the JVM won't actually register it there if I don't declare `package helloworld;` in the HelloWorld class. Now if I try import helloworld in some other class to use it, it will tell me the package doesn't exist. That is the question I tried to formulate to start with --> how can i tell a .png file that it is located in a folder called res?

Comment: The structure of the folders MUST match the structure of the packages. So, if res is in the classpath, and if the image is directly under res, then it's in the default package. If it's under res/com/foo, then it's in the package com.foo. So, in my example, since bin and res are in the classpath, MyClass and Image1.png are both in the same package: com.foo.

Comment: I disagree with your statement. I often put classes in different folders under src solely to keep track of them myself. And when I compile them, they will all be directly under bin, because I haven't actually specified a package for them? (I updated my question)

Comment: You're, once again, confusing class files and source files. Class files end up directly under bin precisely because the compiler enforces the matching between packages and folders. Your Java source file has no package statement, so the class it defines is in the default package, so the generated .class file goes directly under the target directory of javac. If you had `package com.foo;` at the top of your source file, javac would put the .class file in bin/com/foo.

Comment: It's very bad practice to not respect the matching between .java locations and packages. And it's also very bad practice to put classes in the default package. You'll be bitten later if you do this, and you'll even confuse yourself.

Comment: You really confuse me more than I already am, lol. So if by saying `java -cp bin;res com.foo.SomeClass` I tell the JVM to access the SomeClass in the bin folder, and Image1.png in the res folder.. why doesn't it work?

Comment: That is very interesting! It works, and I just got smarter! Thanks a lot for your time and effort :)

Comment: See my edited answer. You're not telling to load classes in bin and images in res. You're telling it to load classes and resources (images or whatever other kind of resources) from bin and from res. You could have .class files in res, and image files in bin if you liked. The class loader (which loads classes and resources) uses a merged tree composed of everything under bin and everything under res.

Comment: Yes, I understand. There was some miscommunication between us because I use a batch-script to compile my code, so it doesn't enforce connection between folder/packages. But it all makes sense now, thank you so very much! :)

Comment: A small thing I wonder, however, is that I usually just enter `java myClass` to run my programs. Does the JVM just assume that the classpath is /bin?

Comment: No. Check your CLASSPATH environment variable: it contains the default classpath if you don't pass the -cp (or -classpath) option.

Answer (score 0):

What API are you referencing `getResource` from?  `java.util.ResourceBundle`?  Make sure the files are referencing the path you put them in, relative to the classpath.  This also requires that you specify the runtime classpath (e.g. `java -classpath`) appropriately.